# Indexing AppFabric Monitoring Database

Tags: sql-server

AppFabric is killing the page life expectancy and disk read metrics on my SQL Server.  Does anyone know if I can add indexes to the AsStaging table or will that break things? There are some very expensive queries happening on that table and there is only a clustered index for a table of almost 300 million records. I know very little about the product except that it is on the way out.  I'm still stuck with it right now though and I have other databases on this SQL instance that will be competing for resources in a big way very soon.